# Monorail - Any C# build tools similar to rails 3 asset pipeline?

Tags: c#, build, assets, castle-monorail

Is there any good asset build tools that will give me the same benefits as the Rails 3 asset pipeline?

Main Functionality I'm seeking:

- See changes instantly on development environment
- Production uses hashed filenames to cachebust
- Built assets that are minified and obfuscated on production, deployable to cdn
- Ability to create combination files via manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/) or [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/), they work with any ASP.NET based web framework.